# Give keycode 2 different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using code to make the spacebar do something for an HTML 5 game. It works great, but the page that displays the game also has a Search Box, and visitors will not be able to use the spacebar properly in the Search Box on that page.

Below is the the code I am using for the spacebar on the game's page.

The Search Box is input type search, so I was wondering if a function could be make for :search, to revert the spacebar to work correctly inside the Search Box.

```
var hit = document.getElementById("hit");

document.onkeydown = function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode == 32) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        hit.click();
    }
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do this, here's one:

```
var hit = document.getElementById("hit");

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (e.currentTarget.type === 'input') { //Or whatever check you want here
      // Do things for your searchBox
      return; //Prevent rest of the function from running
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    hit.click();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the above function you must check if the cursor is in your search box, and if it is then skip the rest of the function

Have rewritten your code as below, hope it helps

```
var hit = document.getElementById("hit");
document.onkeydown = function(e) 
{

if (document.activeElement.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA' && document.activeElement.nodeName != 'INPUT') {

    if (e.keyCode == 32) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        hit.click();
    }
}
};
```

Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the 'keydown' events from the search bar from propagating upwards by calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log('hit!'); 
  e.preventDefault();
});

let search = document.getElementById("search");

search.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("search!");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<form id="search"><input name="query" type="text"><input type="submit" value="search"></form>
```

Comment: would prevent submitting search form by keyboard, if it uses a `type="submit"`

Comment: @charlietfl true, but then you would simply move the stopPropagation to the form-level. Updated the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: yup...simple fix